# how to convert .bmp images to .png in python

Tags: python, image

how to convert .bmp images to .png

this is a part of my code, but it doesn’t convert images to png

```
get_cropped_image(impath).save(outpath,'png')
```

The code is running, but the images don’t change.

Comment: may you try this one... from [PIL package](https://kite.com/python/examples/3024/pil-convert-an-image-to-png-format)

Comment: `get_cropped_image` is not a built-in Python function. Please provide more info.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC everybody got the question. No need for an example even though the body of the question is completely useless, the header is just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use **Pillow** library. Use **glob** to read the **.bmp** images from a folder, **Pillow** to resize and save as .png.

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os

out_dir = ''
cnt = 0
for img in glob.glob('path/to/images/*.bmp'):
    Image.open(img).resize((300,300)).save(os.path.join(out_dir, str(cnt) + '.png'))
    cnt += 1
```

ref: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

Comment: i want to use it in for loop that taking the image path and crop the image and then convert it to png images, i have to give image path not only one image

Comment: @engineer_me: then use that function inside a loop, what's the problem with that?

Comment: Why not use pathlib instead of os.path and glob?

Comment: @AMC this is just a matter of preference I guess.

Comment: Alright, but pathlib is newer and much cleaner overall.

Comment: Agreed, I use that too in most cases, but `glob` and `os` are old school and the syntax is well known by the broader community, hence.

Answer (score 0):

First install `pillow`:

```
pip install pillow
```

Then run this script on the folder with the .bmp files:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os

from pathlib import Path

current_dir = Path('.').resolve()

out_dir = current_dir / "converted"
os.mkdir(out_dir)
cnt = 0

for img in glob.glob(str(current_dir / "*.bmp")):
    filename = Path(img).stem
    Image.open(img).save(str(out_dir / f'{filename}.png'))
```